# Is broadcam BCM4350 compatible for aircrack-ng

Tags: networking

In order to perform wireless attacks does this model support monitor mode and packet injection for kaliLinux.

i tried searching online since two days ,but cannot come to a conclusion weather it supports or not. please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the PCI ID of the device, then check it on [this page of supported broadcom chipsets](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=b43)

Get the ID via:

`lspci -vnn | grep 14e4`

These are the supported ones:

- **b43/wl**
  14e4:4311
  14e4:4313
  14e4:4315
- **b43legacy**
  14e4:4301
  14e4:4306
  14e4:4320
- **b43**
  14e4:4307
  14e4:4312
  14e4:4318
  14e4:4319
  14e4:4320
  14e4:5354

Comment: the pc id [14e4:43a3] ? when i ran the command it showed me this..

Comment: Then it's not supported currently.

Comment: bad luck. but in india other than alfa card are their any other wireless adapters that support kali linux. because alfa cards are costly and tp link network adapter is now currently not supporting kali linux.. please help..

Comment: If you can't find the information by googling, then you should maybe ask that as a new question.